# Adding Animation/Smooth Pan On Setting New Center on ArcGIS JS API Map

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know how I can add smooth animation or Pan function to move to the destination?

As you can see I am trying to re-center the map center by

```
 map.centerAt(new Point(-78.542, 37.61, new SpatialReference({wkid: 4326})));
```

on a click event but this is jumping the map to the destination.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.23/esri/css/esri.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.23/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;

      require(["esri/map", "esri/geometry/Point","esri/SpatialReference","dojo/domReady!"], function(Map, Point, SpatialReference) {
        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "topo",  //For full list of pre-defined basemaps, navigate to http://arcg.is/1JVo6Wd
          center: [-122.45, 37.75], // longitude, latitude
          zoom: 13
        });

        $(".btn").on("click", function(){
           map.centerAt(new Point(-78.542, 37.61, new SpatialReference({wkid: 4326})));
        });

      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Go There</button>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is the esri.config.defaults.map.panDuration config ,( set in milisecond) but for further distance between your point and the centered point , the annimation doesn't work ..

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the map has an "optimizePanAnimation" constructor option that can be set to false to help with panning within the same zoom level.

Here's a link to the documentation. Search the page for "optimizePanAnimation", it's kind of hidden in there.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html

I've been playing around with that property and the [esriConfig settings](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/inside_defaults.html) as well.

```
esriConfig.defaults.map.panDuration = 10000; 
esriConfig.defaults.map.panRate = 1;
esriConfig.defaults.map.zoomDuration = 10000;
esriConfig.defaults.map.zoomRate = 1;
```

Here's another thread that touches on the same question.

https://community.esri.com/thread/207490-how-to-add-animation-smooth-pan-on-setting-new-center-for-map

Here's a working codepen that illustrates the idea:

https://codepen.io/Cofad/pen/vYNaOdw

It's not working perfectly yet. I'm having issues with the tiles not loading quickly enough, but it's a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use the 4.x JavaScript API, then there are some good options in the "GoTo" function of [MapView](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html) and [SceneView](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-SceneView.html) classes.

[Here's a simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gavinr/tdrp5jg9/embedded/result/) of the options for SceneView: https://jsfiddle.net/gavinr/tdrp5jg9/